# React component loads with blur line

Tags: reactjs

[image]

While selecting tab in react the component header comes with blurred line, kindly check and let me know how to remove this bug.

Comment: Please provide more detail about your code

Comment: <div  style={{fontSize:'18px', height:'5px', lineHeight:'1px',}}>
              { props.dashboardData && `Total Revenue From ${props.dashboardData.propertywiseRevenue.length && props.dashboardData.propertywiseRevenue.length} ${props.dashboardData.propertywiseRevenue.length > 1? 'Sites': 'Site'}`}
             </div>

Comment: I removed the lineHeight and its working fine

Comment: @Paul If you found the solution, add an answer to your question. Could be useful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the lineHeight and its working fine